# how to enable sessions in express.js

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have node.js 5.1.1 and express.js 4.13.3.

I read a book and says that in order to enable sessions in express, you have to do `express -e -s nameOfYourProject` when starting a new project. But the book, is a little old, and I get `error: inknow option '-s'`.

The book's example, uses session like so, `var sess = this.req.session;`
. The whole chapter is about signup and login.

So, how do I enable sessions? Do I have to install a module or they are enabled by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not enabled by default, but there is a module available via npm by the express core team. I believe it *used* to be bundled w/ express, but they broke lots of the functionality up into separate modules in express v4. It's quite simple to use and I recommend using Redis or another persistent data store as your session store.

The module: **[express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)**

**Basic usage:**

```
const express = require('express')
const parseurl = require('parseurl')
const session = require('express-session')

let app = express()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var views = req.session.views

  if (!views) {
    views = req.session.views = {}
  }

  // get the url pathname 
  var pathname = parseurl(req).pathname

  // count the views 
  views[pathname] = (views[pathname] || 0) + 1

  next()
})

app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('you viewed this page ' + req.session.views['/foo'] + ' times')
})

app.get('/bar', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('you viewed this page ' + req.session.views['/bar'] + ' times')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out

Comment: No problem! Happy to help